# Convert string to list in python or read xml data as list

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, list, python-2.x

So I'm having an issue where when I read in info from an xml file. The data it reads in is supposed to be a list of numbers but when I read it in, it comes as a string. Is there a way to read xml data as a list or a way to convert a string to a list.

Eg I get the data from the xml as say [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0] and if I check the type it says its a string, ie the whole thing is a string including the brackets and the comma.

Can't wrap my head around how to convert this back to a list of numbers

Comment: `[float(x) for x in mystring.lstrip('[').rstrip(']').strip().split(',')]`

Comment: @AK47 What a magnificent one-liner! Not very helpful for a beginner though...

Comment: @AK47 Yes, that's a good method, worth an upvote (I never even thought about `eval()`! Ususally I avoid it like the plague, but this might be a real application for it!)

Comment: [float(x) for x in mystring.lstrip('[').rstrip(']').strip().split(',')] – AK47 38 mins ago This worked out brilliantly! Thank you!!

Comment: @dege the `eval()` command is cleaner and works in python2 and python3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `eval()` if you want to convert your string to a list of floats

```
>>> string = '[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]'

>>> print(type(string))
<type 'str'>

>>> mylist = eval(string)

>>> print(type(mylist))
<type 'list'>

>>> print([type(x) for x in mylist])
[<type 'float'>, <type 'float'>, <type 'float'>]

>>> print(mylist)
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
```

Comment: Ah forgot to mention I'm trying this in python. So the eval command doesn't work as it's a keyword in maya's version of python libraries

Comment: `eval()` is a builtin for both [python2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) and [python3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval)

Comment: yeah buy maya has it's version of eval() as well so it overwrites python's eval() unfortunately.

Comment: I stand corrected... eval() does work and it is a lot easier... noob mistake of calling maya's version of eval() as maya.cmds.eval() instead of python eval()... I need coffee

Answer (score 2):

For this, you would use the str.split() builtin method.

Set `x = "[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]"`

First of all, get rid of the square brackets around the string:

`x = x[1:-1]` (x is now `"1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0"`, a long string)

Then, split the string to form a list of strings:

`x = x.split(',')` (x is now `["1.0", "2.0", "3.0", "4.0", "5.0"]`, a list of strings)

Then, convert all of these strings into floats (as I assume you want that):

`x = [float(i) for i in x]` (x is now `[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]`, a list of floats)